_Generic length-function fails when default: sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0])
Issue:
Recently I learned about _Generic. In my attempt to use it as a generic length-macro I  stumbled upon a weird issue. While LENA(x) works perfectly fine, the generic LEN(x) fails to compile unless I remove the default one.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENA(x) sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0])
#define LEN(x) _Generic((x), \
    int                : snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d"  , (x)), \
    unsigned int       : snprintf(NULL, 0, "%u"  , (x)), \
    long               : snprintf(NULL, 0, "%ld" , (x)), \
    unsigned long      : snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lu" , (x)), \
    long long          : snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lld", (x)), \
    unsigned long long : snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llu", (x)), \
    float              : snprintf(NULL, 0, "%f"  , (x)), \
    double             : snprintf(NULL, 0, "%f"  , (x)), \
    long double        : snprintf(NULL, 0, "%Lf" , (x)), \
    default            : sizeof((x))/sizeof((x)[0]) \
)

int main() {
    int i = 12345;
    unsigned long ul = 18446744073709551615UL;
    double d = 3.14159;
    char str[] = "Hello, World!";
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    printf("Length of int  : %d\n", LEN(i));    // Output: 5
    printf("Length of Ulong: %d\n", LEN(ul));   // Output: 20
    printf("Length of array: %d\n", LENA(arr)); // Output: 7
    //printf("Length of array: %d\n", LEN(arr));
    //printf("Length of str: %d\n", LEN(str));
    return 0;
}

(specifically the /sizeof((x)[0]-part of it).
Error:
ERROR!
/tmp/21gk5WXdQu.c: In function 'main':
/tmp/21gk5WXdQu.c:15:46: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
   15 |     default            : sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]) \
      |                                              ^
/tmp/21gk5WXdQu.c:25:37: note: in expansion of macro 'LEN'
   25 |     printf("Length of int  : %d\n", LEN(i));    // Output: 5
      |                                     ^~~
ERROR!
/tmp/21gk5WXdQu.c:15:46: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
   15 |     default            : sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]) \
      |                                              ^
/tmp/21gk5WXdQu.c:26:37: note: in expansion of macro 'LEN'
   26 |     printf("Length of Ulong: %d\n", LEN(ul));   // Output: 20
      |                                     ^~~

Outro:
Is this a bug or a feature? I've searched about it, I've tried differect versions of gcc, plenty of tricks, I even asked chatGPT (but I'm not sure if it halucinates or not), so... any idea why this is happening? thanks in advance for any help.

For the record, ChatGPT hallucinates everything. Don’t trust it to write or understand code.

@Giorgos Xou, aside: for generic FP printing, consider snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.*g"  , FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, (x)), snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.*g"  , DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, (x)), snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.*Lg"  , LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG, (x)).  Better to use %g and some precision.

_Generic selects one of the listed expressions. All of the listed items must be valid expressions. If x is not an array or pointer, x[0] is not a valid expression. _Generic is not like a preprocessor directive that can conditionally ignore some code. All of the code in it must be grammatically valid.

Amazing! this does not seem necessary in most cases to me and makes the feature much less useful.

@chqrlie Why is this amazing, if it makes the feature less useful though? lol

@chqrlie IMO, I woudl like _Generic to only use the 1st match, so potential multiple matches like int, int32_t can be used.  This would meet your goal.
